# how do i turn my random list into a integer in python?

Tags: python

I made a list with 3 random numbers and I want to know how to turn it into an integer:

```
import random
list = [random.randint(1,9) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: `len(list)`? what kind of integer are you looking for?

Comment: Do you want to `join` all elements (digits) of the list to form a single integer?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `random.randint(111, 999)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the numbers try this :

```
int(''.join([str(x) for x in my_list]))
```